# WPF DataGrid row template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm very novice to WPF, and I faced a problem:
I need to set row template in DataGrid. It should looks like on following image.

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What part of the image in particular you have hardships to recreate? There is plenty of online documentation and answered questions right here about that subject.

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

To customize a DataGrid use DataGridTemplate column. In the example below the, CustomizedUIElement is some other control that has the layout you desire.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnHeader">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <local:CustomizedUIElement Text="{Binding Path=PropertyToBindTo}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Create a UserControl with the layout you want then inject it into the datagrid as shown above.